# Digitized Shapefile manually using wrong projection: how to fix it?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, digitizing, affine-transformation

I have a raster in correct projection. I used shapefiles, and marked objects (manually), but I found out that my vector layers have different projection, so they have different size and position. Is there a way to correct it using QGIS functional?

[That](http://cs408121.vk.me/v408121585/1099/RIWFC75E7Ec.jpg) is what I see:

[image]

Then, I tried to convert vector projection to raster projection and got [that](http://cs408121.vk.me/v408121585/10a9/J3yKLpdfCV0.jpg):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried an affine transformation? Yours is a typical case for such kind of transformation for cartesian coordinates (i.e., not for lat-lon coordinates).

Basically, you would need to pick at least 3 well spread common points on both your vector and raster layers (for example, a street intersection) and arrange their coordinates in a matrix like this:

```
¦ Xs1 Ys1 1 0 0 0 ¦ | a ¦   ¦ Xt1 ¦
¦ Xs2 Ys2 1 0 0 0 ¦ ¦ b ¦   ¦ Xt2 ¦ 
¦ Xs3 Ys3 1 0 0 0 ¦ ¦ c ¦ = ¦ Xt3 ¦ 
¦ 0 0 0 Xs1 Ys1 1 ¦ ¦ d ¦   ¦ Yt1 ¦ 
¦ 0 0 0 Xs2 Ys2 1 ¦ ¦ e ¦   ¦ Yt2 ¦ 
¦ 0 0 0 Xs3 Ys3 1 ¦ ¦ f ¦   ¦ Yt3 ¦
```

Where `Xs` and `Ys` are coordinates on the source (your vector data) and `Xt` and `Yt` are coordinates on the target (your raster data).

Once you solve that system of equations, you obtain the transformation parameters, which are:

```
a: Scale X 
e: Scale Y
d: Rotation X
b: Rotation Y
c: Translation X
f: Translation Y
```

Then you can use the QGIS plugin 'Affine transformation' placing the calculated parameters in the plugin interface, this way:

[image: Affine transformation parameters]

That's it!

Answer (score 2):

If you digitized the vector layer based on the raster but had a wrong CRS specified for the vector layer, the easiest option should be to simply overwrite the Shapefile's .prj file with the correct CRS information.